# Return of collection field warning - Setters and Constructors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, collections, getter-setter, code-inspection

IntelliJ warns me about "Return of collection field" if I do something like

```
private List<String> myList;

public List<String> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}
```

The description of the code-inspection states:

> Reports any attempt to return an array or Collection field from a method. Since the array or Collection may have its contents modified by the calling method, this construct may result in an object having its state modified unexpectedly. While occasionally useful for performance reasons, this construct is inherently bug-prone.

I totally understand the problems but I wonder why I'm not warned about doing the same for setters and constructors

```
public MyListClass (List<String> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
}

public void setMyList (List<String> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
}
```

which I think can lead to the same problems.

Shouldn't I create new Collections for both getting and setting the Collection? So not only

```
return new ArrayList<String>(this.myList);
```

but also

```
this.myList = new ArrayList<String>(myList);
```

(Ignoring making returned lists unmodifiable or checking for null in this example)

Comment: A setter*explicitly* accepts data created outside the class. A getter *may* be inappropriately exposing internal dependencies. But yes, it may lead to the same type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Java | Assignment issues | Assignment to Collection or array field from parameter` inspection to get warnings in setters and constructors too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is only to promote standard coding practices.

The warning mentioned above would enforce the developer to have immutable collections inside a class.

You may safely ignore this warning or alternatively you can suppress the inspection.

You can read about it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/suppressing-inspections.html